# Given a characteristic polynomial of a Matrix, prove a certain Matrix is equal to 0

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, linear-transformations

I've been trying to solve this issue:

> Let $A$ be a diagnosable $n\times n$ matrix. It's characteristic polynomial is: $p(t) = a_n t^n +a_{n-1}t^{n-1}+...+a_1t+a_0$.
>
> Given the square $n\times n$ matrix $p(A)=a_nA^n+a_{n-1}A^{n-1}+...+a_1A+a_0$, prove that $p(A)=0$

We can deduce that $a_n = 1$, and that $a_{n-1}=-tr(A)$, or the minus the sum of all eigenvalues.
But I'm not sure what more can we find out about the given characteristic polynomial.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks to the help of Sam Freedman, a solution was found.

Matrix A is diagnosable, which means it is similar to a diagonal Matrix D:

$A = P^-1DP$

That means we can define $p(A)$ with matrix D:

$p(P^-1DP) = P^-1(D^n +a_{n-1}D^{n-1}+...+a_1D+a_0)P$

We can conclude that matrix $p(A)$ is similar to a diagonal matrix, described above.

Matrix $D$ can be broken down to: $diag(d_1,...,d_n)$. And the diagonal matrix $p(A)$ is similar to can will have the value: $d_i^n+a_{n-1}d_i^{n-1}+...+a_1d_i +a_0$, which means those are the eigenvalues of $p(A)$.

Now, thanks to knowing the characteristic polynomial of $A$, we know that the group $d_1,...,d_n$ are the roots of said polynomial, meaning they send it to 0.

And the form of each eigenvalue of $p(A)$ is equal to the form of said characteristic polynomial. Which means each eigenvalue of $p(A)$ is equal to 0.

The diagonal matrix $p(A)$ is similar to must be the zero matrix. And the zero matrix is the only matrix which is similar to itself, and therefore we can conclude and claim:

$p(A) = 0$

Many thanks, Sam Freedman!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the famous [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem), but we can also prove this special diagonalizable case directly.

Writing $A = P^{-1} D P$, we use a standard trick to compute out
\begin{align*}
p(A) = p( P^{-1} D P) &= ( P^{-1} D P)^n + a_{n - 1}( P^{-1} D P)^{n - 1} + \dots + a_1 ( P^{-1} D P) + a_0I \\
&=  P^{-1} D^n P + a_{n - 1}P^{-1} D^{n - 1} P + \dots + a_1 ( P^{-1} D P) + a_0I\\
&= P^{-1}( D^n + a_{n - 1} D^{n - 1} + \dots + a_1 D + a_0I ) P. 
\end{align*}

Now we've reduced the problem to the case of a diagonal matrix. Given what you know about the characteristic polynomial of a diagonal matrix, can you go from here?

Comment: So, we can claim that p(A) is similar to a diagonal matrix. 
I would say that for the characteristic polynomial of a diagonal matrix, it's made of the product of $(x - \lambda_i)$ for each eigenvalue of the matrix.

I'm failing to understand how can I connect this information, to the diagonal matrix being the zero matrix. I would assume the characteristic polynomial would have to be $x^n$. But I'm not sure how to get there.

Comment: First note that for a diagonal matrix $D = \text{diag}(d_1, \cdots, d_n)$, the eigenvalues are in fact the diagonal elements. This makes the characteristic polynomial $(x - d_1)\cdots(x - d_n)$, so it's actually pretty far from $x^n$.

Comment: My suggestion then is explicitly to plug in the diagonal matrix $D$ into the last line of my answer, add it all together and see what you get. Note that $D^k = \text{diag}(d_1^k, \cdots, d_n^k)$

Comment: So, each eigenvalue of the diagonal matrix would be equal to the sum $d_i^n + a_{n-1}d_i^{n-1}+...+a_1d_i+a0$? Can I find out that each of this sum somehow equals to 0?

Comment: You’re right, that sum does equal zero. You’ll need to connect the characteristic polynomial of $D$ to the original characteristic polynomial for $A$.

Comment: Thank you for keeping up with my slowness, Sam. So, we know that the characteristic polynomial of D is the same of A. And so the group $d_1,...,d_n$ turns the characteristic polynomial to 0, since they're roots of it. Since we're using the same scalars, $a_{n-1},...,a_0$, that should be the same, then? And we find out that p(A) is similar to the zero matrix?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119105/discussion-between-sam-freedman-and-eatay-mizrachi).